# Line appears broken into two geometries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, editing, features

I have a shapefile with line features. One of my lines was causing problems in a python script and in the QGIS interface it appeared as two segments (one long one with a brief gap between two nodes).

I used the calculator with `num_geometries( $geometries)` and it showed this entry has two geometries (all the others had one). I imagine this is the problem. Is there any way to fix this and merge them back to a single geometry? Deleting and re-digitizing would be a lot of effort. I didn't see anything in the Validity checker and it didn't complain, but that might be because I messed up a parameter.

The merge tools in QGIS digitizing bar is not relevant. It is for merging multiple features, not multiple gometries in one feature -- it complains I have only one feature selected.

Comment: Try if explode lines (your selected line) and afterwards a re-merging solves the problem. Multipart to single-part-geometry might be worth a try as well.

Answer (score 4):

You have a multi-line geometry.

You can use the *Merge lines* algorithm after you have connected the the two parts, so that they form a continuous line.

You can also split the multi-geometry into two (simple) geometries using the *Multipart to single parts* algorithm, join them (using the *Vertex Tool* in the *Digitizing Toolbar*) to form a continuous line and then combine them into one line using the *Merge Selected Features* tool in the *Advanced digitizing toolbar".